Conflict between `tcolorbox` and `auto-pst-pdf`
I'm using the texlive/2024 distribution.
The following MWE fails to compile correctly.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{psvectorian}

\begin{document}

\psvectorian[mirror]{2}

\end{document}

I would like to have the following output but this MWE produces a white page.
What can be done to solve this issue?


Maybe try the pgfornament package instead which has the same ornaments more or less as far as I know but uses PGF which is also used by tcolorbox.

Thanks @JasperHabicht; that's exactly what I needed.

If you really need this combination you can just use tcolorbox on the main document, with pdflatex, and skip it on the inner call that uses latex and handles the pstricks code.
\documentclass{article}
\ifnum\pdfoutput=1
  \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\fi
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{psvectorian}

\begin{document}

\psvectorian[mirror]{2}

\end{document}


Thank you, it works. Can you explain me in which case the package tcolorbox won't be loaded? In that case, it will raise an error if I use some of the command defined by tcolorbox, won't it?

only if you use tcolorbox inside code that is passed to pstricks: the package extracts each pstricks picture to a sparate document, compiles that with latex to make a pdf that is then included into the main document. @Colas

That's very clear, thank you.

My suggestion would be to use the pgfornament package instead which offers more or less the same ornamental symbols and is build upon PGF like the tcolorbox package. This way, you won't easily run into conflicts:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
%\usepackage{psvectorian}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\begin{document}

%\psvectorian[mirror]{2}
\pgfornament[symmetry=v]{2}

\end{document}


